# Check if month pass in datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datetime, datetimepicker

I have an calculator that calculates the hourdiff between two datetime values.
I want when selected month ends and new month start the calculation starts from the beginning.
Now all goes ok for Feb month but when somebody want start calc from March then it calculates for 28 days and not for 31
My Code:

```
<script>
     $(function () {
         $('#frompicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'd/M/yy' });
         $('#topicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'd/M/yy' });
     });
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function calculateTime() {

            //get values

            var valuestart = $("#frompicker").val();
            var valuestop = $("#topicker").val();

            //alert(valuestart);
            var timeStart = new Date(valuestart);
            var timeEnd = new Date(valuestop);

            var hourDiff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 3600000;

                if (hourDiff < 0) {
                    $("p").html("<b>price:</b> " + "wrong data" );

     else if (hourDiff > 24&& hourDiff <= 672) { //28days
                    $("p").html("<b>price:</b> " + "100.00" + "€");
                }
    else if (hourDiff >= 672) { //
                    var hourDiffnew = hourDiff - 672;

                    var finalpricep61 = (hourDiffnew * 0.125) + 90;
                    var finalpricep62 = finalpricep61.toFixed();


                    $("p").html("<b>price:</b> " + finalpricep62 + ".00€");

                }
```

Comment: Don't you have it hard-coded to give you different results for 1-28 days and greater than 28 days?

Comment: yes , this must be changed , but because of datetime format i can t handle this.I try but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
var valuestart = $("#frompicker").val();
```

what is *valuestart*? A string or timevalue? If it's a string, then likely the following will not work as expected in some browsers:

```
var timeStart = new Date(valuestart);
var timeEnd = new Date(valuestop);
```

Assuming these Date objects have appropriate values, and that:

> when selected month ends and new month start the calculation starts from the beginning

means start from the beginning of the month, then:

```
if (timeStart.getMonth() != timeEnd.getMonth()) {
  timeStart.setDate(1);
  timeStart.setMonth(timeEnd.getMonth());
}
```

will set *timeStart* to the first of the same month as *timeEnd*. But I might have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: value start is a datetime value like : 10/Feb/2014 00:00 ( or 02/10/2014 00:00) . I m really thank you about answer

Comment: At last i want to check for example :  if (hourDiff > 312 && hourDiff <= "last day of month") {
$("p").html("<b>price:</b> " + "100.00" + "€");} .How can i declare this "last day of month"?